# Вывод многослойных списков

Tags: python

При выводе списка, имеющего больше одного слоя, он выводится подобным видом (например: `[1, [...], 2]`)
  Как можно реализовать подобный вывод, то есть вывод двух слоев списка(например: `[1, [1, [...], 2], 2]` или `[1, [1, ...] ]`, и т.д.)?

Comment: Приведите пример списка, который у вас сокращается таким способом.  И как именно вы его выводите. У меня отображаются все вложенные списки, если только это не список, вложенный сам в себя.

Comment: А вообще, есть только два способа переопределить вывод - 1). либо создать новый класс, унаследовав его от list и переопределив `__str__` и/или `__repr__` 2). Либо делать вывод не стандартными способами, а специально написанной функцией.

Comment: @Александр Как раз необходима функция. Конкретно в примере необходимо вывести два слоя фрактала, т.е список, который ссылается сам на себя внутрь до бесконечности

Comment: где вы прочитали подобную терминологию: "фракталы", "многослойные списки" для описания контейнеров, которые ссылки сами на себя могут содержать (self-referential)? Приведите ссылку с определениями. Пример самоссылающиеся cписка: `L=[1, None, 2]; L[1] = L`

Comment: Просто в вашем примере совсем не "фрактал". Если на первом слое в первой ячейке 1, то в любом другом слое в первой ячейке тоже будет 1. Тройки там быть уже не может.

Comment: @Александр Поправил примеры. Примеры в списках не являлись фракталами, но просто были даны для примера необходимого вывода. Ссылку дать не могу, но ошибки, назвав такой самоссылающийся список фракталом, не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ext_list_repr(l):
    return '[%s]' % ', '.join(repr(el) for el in l)
```